# Integrating a link preview image scraper, into link and tab generation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, promise, fetch-api

I'm trying to integrate months of React and Redux learning, into a project that creates an app from Reddit's api. In my case i'll be calculating dissent and having it post automatically to a subreddit. That along with a simple downvote viewer.

Anyway, as part of this project, i'm recreating Reddit posts but removing any algorithmic or social influence over people's initial response. This is where i've hit a stumbling block. Actually two and i may as well address both, to save from cluttering stackOverFlow. I'm currently struggling to take the .jpg addresses i've scrapped and then integrate these promises into an img tab. My promise fetchs don't return values to my media tab creation function. Even although my homemade scrapper does find og:img and successfully extracts .jpg addresses. My second issue, is that when i take video addresses from reddit's .json and add them to <video src={scrapped address} type="video/mp4">, they never have any audio. Anyway, thank you for any direction here, my code is as follows.

My url image preview scrapper:

```
export const fetchPreviewImage = async(url) => {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const resText =  await res.text();
    const resArray = resText.split(' ');
    const urlPosition = (resArray.indexOf('property="og:image"') + 1);
    const untreatedUrl = resArray[urlPosition];
    const imageUrl = untreatedUrl.match(/\"(.*?)\"/gm).toString();
    console.log(imageUrl);
    return imageUrl;
}
```

My call to this function and also my integration of video links is:

```
const mediaExtract = (key) => {
    let media 
    if(jsonRes[key].data.is_video){ 
      media = <video src={jsonRes[key].data.media.reddit_video.fallback_url} type="video/mp4" width="70%" height="auto" controls></video> 
    } else if (jsonRes[key].data.post_hint === 'link'){
       
        fetchPreviewImage([jsonRes[key].data.url]).then((res) => {
          media = 
          <a href={jsonRes[key].data.url}>
            <img src={res} alt="Link Image Preview" width="70%" height="auto"/>
          </a> 
          
        })   
          setTimeout(() => {return media}, 1000);
    }
```

The errors i get are as follows:

ImageScraper.js:2 => Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch,

The resource https://images.theconversation.com/files/472783/original/file-20220706-23-w1vbdw.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&rect=0%2C0%2C5542%2C3689&q=45&auto=format&w=926&fit=clip was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally

has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value

The rest just don't show at all, with no error logs

Comment: I've not solved this problem yet but i'm 100% sure it relates to the asynchronous nature of fetch. So far i've tried to delay the return to no avail.

While i've been able to get the response outside of the function, it will not allow me to then inject it via jsx, into the browser. My next venture will be to integrate my scrapper, in some way, so that that it operates in tandum with my createAsyncThunk fetch request to the reddit api. If i can parse the data i need during initialisation, then maybe i can use the data similarly to the reddit.json data. 

I'll report back to myself lol.

Comment: "*Failed to fetch, the resource has been blocked by CORS policy*" is a quite clear error message

Comment: Unfortunately this error message only relates to about 10% or less of the links that i can't seem to get from fetch to jsx injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i had to come at this whole thing from a different angle.

My first point was to focus my coding solution, into a single solution, for a single problem. Separation of concerns, as the rule book says.

I integrated both the call to reddit.json and the PreviewImageURL generator, into a singular process, detaching it from the creation of the HTML tabs and instead viewing it through the context of pure data retrieval and storing. The rest would come later, i just needed to retrieve the urls and store them.

Therefore, taking this new tact, i was able to iterate through the reddit.json and create an array of objects. I stored any preview image urls, with their respective key number, giving me the ability to automate retrieval, when iterating through the reddit.json during tab creation.

I've only been learning code for 9 months but this whole thing has been a big step up for me. The joys of being self taught, you don't readily have a mentor to help solve roadblocks and those roadblocks don't always have easily answered or asked questions. You've just got to deconstruct each concept and see if there is an avenue for further progress. One issue i ran into here, is that you cannot use forEach to iterate through promises, i had to use for(const key in keys)

I just put my revised solution below into an asyncthunk and used the redux store, to populate the tabs.

Current issues with this code, that i'm trying to resolve, is node not allowing over 11 listeners. Using process and importing the emitter class, then wrapping the whole thing in emit; using emitter.setMaxListeners - doesn't work. Nothing i do seems to allows me to set this limit to 100. It's rather bizarre how difficult getting this seemingly crucial information is.

The only current workaround i have for this, is a ten page listing. Anyway my code is below, you'll be able to use it for your own URL preview image scraping, if you refactor it.

```
const fetchPreviewImage = async(url) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${url}`);
    const resText = await res.text();
    const resArray = resText.split(' ');
    const urlPosition = (resArray.indexOf('property="og:image"') + 1);
    const imageUrl = resArray[urlPosition];
    if(imageUrl.match(/\"(.*?)\"/gm) != null){
        return imageUrl.match(/\"(.*?)\"/gm).toString()
    } else {
        return
    }
}

const dataIteration = async() => {
    const response = await fetch('https://www.reddit.com//hot.json?limit=10')
    const json = await response.json();
    const data = await json.data.children;
    const keys = await Object.keys(data);
    const result = {};
    for(const key in keys){
       if(data[key].data.post_hint == 'link'){
         const injection = await fetchPreviewImage(data[key].data.url);
         if(injection != undefined){
           result[key] = injection;
         }
       }
    } 
    return result;
}

//in my actual application of this i wrapped it into a single function and call it in an asyncthunk
```